# Ant build xml from Eclipse and Team City

Tags: eclipse, ant, teamcity

I exported an ANT build.xml file from eclipse, I wasnted to use it for my TeamCity builds. I am getting the following error when running my builds. Any ides as to what could cause this.

`Process exited with code 1
[13:44:24]Ant output
[13:44:24][Ant output] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher
[13:44:24][Ant output] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[13:44:24][Ant output]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
[13:44:24][Ant output] Could not find the main class: org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.  Program will exit.
[13:44:24][Ant output] Exception in thread "main" 
[13:44:24]Publishing internal artifacts
[13:44:24]Build finished`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the Android sdk to the build server, and run the SDK manager exe to pull down the needed google api. On top of that reference the path to the SDK in my local.properties file in my Android project after that things worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher cannot be found.  I'm guessing that you don't have the ant jars on the classpath when you are launching your ant build file.